# Electron - Subpixel antialiasing does not work

Tags: css, fonts, electron, antialiasing, subpixel

How can I configure Electron to use subpixel-antialiasing?
I tried using:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
backface-visibility: visible !important;
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased !important;
```

But this does not appear to have any effect. I am using version 1.8.2 of Electron.